# Lower upper function not working in string search

Tags: mysql, sql

im new to mysql. my problem is

```
select ename
from emp
where ename=lower('BLAKE')
```

the result will give  BLAKE  with uppercase letter. why does the lower function not working? did i miss something? i tried collate but not working

Comment: The case sensitivity of comparisons is determined by the collation associated with the column/table/database/server.  Read more about collations:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-general.html.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
select ename from emp where lower(ename)=lower('BLAKE') And if  you want to as result into lower then 

select lower(ename)as ename from emp where lower(ename)=lower('BLAKE')
```